# Azure devops. Howto guide on deploying to own server. What steps to take?

Tags: azure-devops

My scenario is this:

- I use BitBucket, and track everything there
- My project consist of .cshtml files and static assets
- JS and CSS (scss) needs to be minified. I use gulp for this.
- npm needs to be installed.

What I need to have happen is this:

- When I push to master I need to deploy those changes to a deployment server (not azure - my own dedicated windows server)
- I need to run npm to make sure everything is installed
- I need to run gulp

How would I go about doing this? Especially the part about pushing changes to deployment server in the correct path.

Any advice would be welcome.

Comment: What does this have to do with Azure DevOps?

Comment: Azure Devops pipelines?

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy to your own servers using Azure Pipelines. You can use Deployment Groups to perform the deployment by installing an agent on the target server. Check [this](https://www.azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/deploymentgroups/) guide to deploy to VMs. In this guide, the VM is running on Azure, but you should be able to follow the guide and set up to your own target servers.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your server as an agent:[Azure Pipelines agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser)

Then create a release,In the task tab, set the agent pool is your server.

[image]

all the job will run in your server.